# Swift: generic power function as infix operator

Tags: swift, generics

Below is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29723695/5098863) to the original question of how to add a power operator for `Int` numbers:

```
infix operator ^^ { associativity left precedence 160 }
func ^^ (radix: Int, power: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(pow(CGFloat(radix), CGFloat(power)))
}
```

How would one generalise this so that it works for `Double`, `Float`, and `Int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "generalize" it. You have to implement it for each type separately.

If you look in the Swift header, you will see that that is exactly what Swift itself does for the built-in operators such as `+`. There is no "general" `+` function; there is one `+` function for every numeric type.

Thus:

```
infix operator ^^ { associativity left precedence 160 }
func ^^ (radix: Int, power: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(pow(CGFloat(radix), CGFloat(power)))
}
func ^^ (radix: Double, power: Double) -> Double {
    return Double(pow(CGFloat(radix), CGFloat(power)))
}
// ... and so on for as many types as you like ...
```

Comment: But if I copy the code and replace all `Int` with `Double`, I get a compiler error "operator redeclared"

Comment: @fiship you might find the `pow` function useful for `Double` and the like

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned - you declare the `operator` once but the `func` many times.

Comment: @fiship Consider that if you just substitute `Int` with `Double` you are squeezing doubles into cgfloat ... it might lead to some nasty bugs.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was missing this bit of how to connect the `func` and the `operator` like that