# Defining Exponent operator

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

Has there been a change to this process now that the final release of Xcode is out? I've tried the following [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116205/how-to-declare-exponent-power-operator-with-new-precedencegroup-in-swift-3) but it's just not working. It's like "pow" is not recognized. I get the error *Use of unresolved identifier 'pow'*. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import the module where the function `pow` is defined:

```
import Foundation
```