# C++ program produces different output on different machines

Tags: c++

I was solving [this](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1/B) problem on codeforces, and I wrote the code in C++. This is the quick(but bad) solution :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,r,c,temp,len,i;
    char str[100];
    char rem;
    string res;

    cin >> n;
    while(n--)
    {
        r = c = -1;
        res = "";

        scanf("%s",str);
        sscanf(str, "R%dC%d",&r,&c);

        if(r != -1 && c != -1)
        {
            /* RC type */
            temp = c;
            if(c%26 == 0)
                temp--;
            while(temp)
            {
                rem = 'A' + (temp%26 - 1);
                res = res + rem;
                temp = temp / 26;
            }
            if(c%26 == 0)
                res.at(0) = res.at(0) + 1;

            reverse(res.begin(), res.end());
            cout << res << r << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            /* normal type */
            len = strlen(str);
            r = 0;
            c = 0;
            temp = 0;
            for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
                {
                    r = r + pow(10,len-i-1) * (str[i] - '0');
                }
                else
                {
                    c = c + pow(26,temp)*(str[i] - 'A' + 1);
                    temp++;
                }
            }
            cout << "R" << r << "C" << c << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If this is the input :

```
2
R23C55
BC23
```

my Linux 64-bit gcc gives this output :

```
BC23
R23C55
```

But the online judge is giving this output :

```
BC23
R23C54
```

I have used proper brackets, no indefinite increment/decrement operator to ensure exact same order od evaluation of things on both the machines, but still something is there that is resulting in undefined evaluation. Can anyone please help what statement has undefined behaviour. AFAIK, the solution has no such statement. Please help.

**EDIT**
I used `ceil()` around the `pow()` and passed the test case. Although, I am scared now. I am now worried how to be sure of the value returned from pow(), since [there is a good reason of not implementing pow to return int type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398442/why-isnt-int-powint-base-int-exponent-in-the-standard-c-libraries)

Comment: It is not `C/C++`, it is simply `C++`.

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth : I have been scratching my head from past 1 hour, but either I am overlooking something or simply something is wrong...

Comment: @pzaenger, @Dmitri, doesn't presence of `stdio.h`, `string.h`, `scanf`, etc make it a C/C++ program?

Comment: @InnocentBystander No, because there is no C/C++.

Comment: @InnocentBystander `using namespace std;` definitely isn't valid c syntax.
`

Comment: arguments over tagging aside, apple clang agrees with you in both release and debug builds.

Comment: This may just be a bit of floating point fuzz coming out of `pow` getting rounded differently. What happens if you recode the loop to remain in integers the whole way through?

Comment: @user4581301 Floating point is not the culprit here. An integer raised to integer power is an integer, `pow` produces a `double` given an integer, and `double` precisely represents integers up to 53 bits long.

Comment: No reason to use FP [and it may be slower]. Try `int pow26 = 1; ... c = c + pow26 * (str[i] - 'A' + 1); ... pow26 *= 26;`. Likewise for the `pow(10,...)`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, melpomene, by C/C++ I meant mixture of C and C++

Comment: If you're unsure about accuracy of `pow()` then you should write your own function as others suggest. If you keep it, then write a test program to compare `pow()` with the correct result on all platforms and then you'll know for sure how to adjust the result. `ceil()` doesn't sound right, shouldn't it be rounded up or down?

Comment: Are you still having issues? I was intrigued so I wrote my own version from scratch using a different approach [it runs 15x faster] and passes all the practice tests. I also ran your version, and it seems to have issues on some edge cases [some are in the practice tests] and outputs an `@` instead. For example, for an input of `R785221C773428`, the correct output is `AQZCF785221` but your program [as of yesterday] seems to be producing `AR@CF785221`

Answer (score 1):

Maxim Sabyanin's comment might be a possible solution. If you are only interested in integers, then either do a floor or ceil of the result of pow. I have faced a similar issue before. You can write a simple implementation of pow as shown below

```
int exponent(int base_number, int power)
{
    if(power==0)
        return 1;
    int i;//multiplication counter
    int current_product=1;
    for(i=0; i<power; i=i+1)
    {
        current_product=current_product*base_number;
    }
    return current_product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I used `ceil()` around the `pow()` and passed the test case.

That's a good reason to avoid `pow` in such cases. It's not too hard to implement a function that works with integral types and doesn't suffer from the floating point precision issues.

```
int int_pow(int x, unsigned int n)
{
   int ret = 1;
   while (n--)
   {
      ret *= x;
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Note that if this becomes a performance bottleneck, you can use a slightly modified version.

```
int int_pow(int x, unsigned int n)
{
   if ( n == 0 )
   {
      return 1;
   }

   return (int_pow(x, n/2) * (n%2 == 0 ? 1 : x));
}
```