# Why is my arithmetic with a long long int behaving this way?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, long-long

I'm trying to calculate large integers with the `long long` datatype but when it gets large enough (`2^55`), the arithmetic behavior is unpredictable. I am working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

In this first case, I am subtracting `2` from the `long long` variable `m` in the initialization. This works fine for all `n` until I try `54`, then `m` will simply not be subtracted by `2`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

#define LL long long

int main()
{
    LL n;
    cin >> n;
    LL m = pow(2, n + 1) - 2;
    cout << m;
    return 0;
}
```

However, using this code `m` does get subtracted by `2` and is working as I would expect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

#define LL long long

int main()
{
    LL n;
    cin >> n;
    LL m = pow(2, n + 1);
    m -= 2;
    cout << m;
    return 0;
}
```

I expect both codes to be equivalent, why is this not the case?

Comment: I'm curious where you picked up `#define LL long long`. I see it pretty often on this site, but I'm not aware of who or what is propagating it. Edit : Is it another one of those code golf habits?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's used a lot in programming challenges to save typing time.

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is considered bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I guess Its just a bit of lazziness.. Due to the `#define` all occurences of `LL` will be replaced by `long long` at compile time

Comment: @Lucas but `using LL = long long` is also compile time, same size to type, and better. There is no reason to use a macro there

Comment: Prefer to use *bit shifting* instead of `pow(2, N)`, such as `(1 << N)`.  Bit shifting uses integers and most processors have a single instruction for shifting.

Comment: @L.F. Don't randomly push stuff like that without understanding why. `using namespace std;` is _perfectly_ fine when writing code examples.

Comment: @pipe: We understand perfectly well why. We don't want to promote bad practices just because you think it's "magically fine" for code examples. There are plenty of code examples on this site that were broken by `using namespace std;`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews when you're telling people to prefer bit-shift for *signed* integer types, please alert them that for signed integer types overflow is *undefined behavior*, that this is not just theoretical undefined behavior but can create actual bugs on common compilers like `gcc`, and that the numerical result can be surprising and unexpected if you don't consciously think about overflow even when it is compiled to behave exactly as expected for a fixed-width integer type.

Comment: Minor nit unrelated to your problem: prefer `typedef` or `using`  to `#define` for types. Simple lexical substitution can blow up on you, but with `typedef`, the compiler knows what’s going on.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The issue with

```
LL m = pow(2, n + 1) - 2;
```

is that `pow(2, n + 1)` is not a `long long`.  It has the type `double` (refer to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)) and because the value is so large, subtracting `2` from it will not change its value.  That means that `m` will not have the correct value.  As you have already found, you need to assign the result first and then do the subtraction.  Another alternative is to write your own `pow` that will return a integer type when given an integer type so you can do the raising to the power and subtraction at the same time.

Comment: For the OP:  You should use bit shifting instead of `pow()` function.  Something like `(1 << (n + 1))`.

Comment: @StackDanny The problem is at `pow(2, 54)`, not `pow(2, 53)`

Comment: Good answer but you should probably mention that the reason it works in the second example is that `pow(2,n)` "accidentally" fits exactly in the most commonly used floating point representation, even for very large results, so there is never a round-off error involved.

Comment: @pipe, for powers of two and binary computers, it's not an "accident" in any way.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you'll need `1ULL << (n + 1)` to shift more than 31 bits

Comment: _"Another alternative is to write your own pow"_ -- you can't be seriously suggesting that? There must be a standard implementation, somewhere. To reinvent the square wheel is the worst advice.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I am serious.  There is no `pow` implementation that gives you an integer in C++.  You have to write your own or get on from some third party library.

Comment: I believe you that this is an oversight in the standard library ([until recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398442/why-isnt-int-powint-base-int-exponent-in-the-standard-c-libraries)). By "standard", I meant in some highly-used general-purpose 3rd-party library like Boost.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev that overload still returns a `double`.

Answer (score 19):

> I expect both codes to be equivalent, why is this not the case?

Your expectation is wrong. Your second code would be equivalent to this:

```
auto m = static_cast<LL>( pow(2, n + 1) ) - 2;
```

as due to conversion rule for [arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) and the fact that [`std::pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) returns `double` in this case:

> For the binary operators (except shifts), if the promoted operands have different types, additional set of implicit conversions is applied, known as usual arithmetic conversions with the goal to produce the common type (also accessible via the std::common_type type trait). If, prior to any integral promotion, one operand is of enumeration type and the other operand is of a floating-point type or a different enumeration type, this behavior is deprecated. (since C++20)
>
> If either operand has scoped enumeration type, no conversion is performed: the other operand and the return type must have the same type
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is long double, the other operand is converted to long double
>
> **Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other operand is converted to double**
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other operand is converted to float
>
> ...

(emphasis is mine) your original expression would lead to `double` - `double` instead of `long long int` - `long long int` as you do in the second case hence the difference.

Answer (score 17):

The `pow` function returns a value of type `double`, which only has 53 bits of precision.  While the returned value will fit in a `double` even if `n` is greater than 53, subtracting 2 results in a value of type `double` that requires more than 53 bits of precision so the result of the subtraction is rounded to the nearest representable value.

The reason breaking out the subtraction works is because the `double` value returned from `pow` is assigned to a `long long`, then you subtract an `int` from a `long long`.

Since you're not dealing with floating point numbers and you're only raising 2 to a power, you can replace the call to `pow` with a simple left shift:

```
LL m = (1LL << (n + 1)) - 2;
```

This keeps all intermediate values at type `long long`.