# Performance of pow(x,3.0f) vs x*x*x?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

The following program...

```
int main() {
    float t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1'000'000'000; i++) {
        const float x = i;
        t += x*x*x;
    }
    return t;
}
```

...takes about 900ms to complete on my machine.  Whereas...

```
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    float t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1'000'000'000; i++) {
        const float x = i;
        t += std::pow(x,3.0f);
    }
    return t;
}
```

...takes about 6600ms to complete.

I'm kind of suprised that the optimizer doesn't inline the std::pow function so that the two programs produce the same code and have identical performance.

Any insights?  How do you account for the 5x performance difference?

For reference I'm using gcc -O3 on Linux x86

**Update: (C Version)**

```
int main() {
    float t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        const float x = i;
        t += x*x*x;
    }
    return t;
}
```

...takes about 900ms to complete on my machine.  Whereas...

```
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        const float x = i;
        t += powf(x,3.0f);
    }
    return t;
}
```

...takes about 6600ms to complete.

**Update 2**

The following program:

```
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        const float x = i;
        t += __builtin_powif(x,3.0f);
    }
    return t;
}
```

runs in 900ms like the first program.

Why isn't `pow` being inlined to `__builtin_powif` ?

**Update 3:**

With `-ffast-math` the following program:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1'000'000'000; i++) {
            const float x = i;
            t += powf(x, 3.0f);
    }
    std::cout << t;
}
```

runs in 227ms (as does the `x*x*x` version).  That's 200 picoseconds per iteration.  Using `-fopt-info` it says `optimized: loop vectorized using 16 byte vectors` and `optimized: loop with 2 iterations completely unrolled` so I guess that means its doing iterations in batches of 4 for SSE and doing 2 iterations at once pipelining (for a total of 8 iterations at once), or something like that?

Comment: What happens if you use `pow(x, 3)`?

Comment: Your call to `std::pow` uses a floating point value as exponent (you can calculate roots with it), while `x*x*x` is way more simple.

Comment: As you should know, please don't tag both C and C++ unless the question really is about both languages (translation between them or similar). Your code is C++ specific and can't be built with a C compiler.

Comment: @Barmar: Same result.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: C translation added.

Comment: And what happens if you use the correct function `powf` instead of the double precision one?

Comment: Also, isn't this calculation going to overflow in terrible ways?

Comment: You might get a more reliable measurement if you call `pow` in advance of the loop, then time just the loop part.

Comment: @klutt: I removed the comment - I had miscounted the number of zeros in the long constants.

Comment: Since you're using GCC, try `t += __builtin_powif(x, 3)` -- the results should be illuminating.

Comment: @TravisGockel: `__builtin_powif(x, 3.0f)` does indeed produce 900ms result.  Why isnt `pow` being inlined to `__builtin_powif(x, 3.0f)` ?

Comment: I tend to agree that GCC should be smart enough to figure out that `std::pow` is the same thing...what version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @TravisGockel: `gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

Comment: Try `-ffast-math`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Wow, with `-ffast-math` it runs in 227ms.  wtf

Comment: Add `-fopt-info` and it will tell you that it vectorized the loop. The final result is likely different though.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I changed the loop bound to be dynamic based on `stoi(argv[1])`, still performed 227ms.  I then added `-fopt-info` and indeed it says: `optimized: loop vectorized using 16 byte vectors`.  So it must be SSE vectorizing 4 iterations at once.  This explains the 200 picosecond iteration time which is below one clock cycle.  It still seems insanely fast, even considering that.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: It also says `optimized: loop with 2 iterations completely unrolled` so I guess that means its doing two iterations at once for a total of 8 at once maybe.

Comment: The unrolling is probably just the last few iterations (in case it isn't a multiple of 4).

Comment: `-march=native` would likely give you AVX vectorization, unless your processor is very old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc page about [gcc builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) is explicit (emphasize mine):

> Built-in Function: double __builtin_powi (double, int)
>
> Returns the first argument raised to the power of the second. **Unlike the pow function no guarantees about precision and rounding are made**.

> Built-in Function: float __builtin_powif (float, int)
>
> Similar to __builtin_powi, except the argument and return types are float.

As `__builtin_powif` has equivalent performances to a a mere product, it means that the additional time is used to the controls required by `pow` for its guarantees about precision and rounding.

Comment: Ok, so `x*x*x` and `powf(x,3)` will produce a different result for some values of x?  That makes sense then I guess, if powf is more precise.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: I would assume yes. The only real way to go further is to examine the source code of `pow`/`powf` in gcc library.

Comment: Interestingly, this behavior changed in C++11. The libstdc++ definition of `std::pow` which uses `__builtin_powif` only happens in `#if __cplusplus < 201103L`.

Comment: @TravisGockel I belive that's due to [`std::pow` (7)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) *"If any argument has integral type, it is cast to `double`"*. [Here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/cmath.syn) only the floating point overloads are listed. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626234/4944425

Answer (score 0):

% Assuming your compiler chose to just call `pow` in the shared library like https://godbolt.org/z/re3baK (without `-ffast-math`)

I did not take a look at how `pow(float, float)` is implemented, but I see some points.

1. `x*x*x` is inlined while `pow` can't be as it is in a shared library - function call overhead difference
2. Whether the exponent `3.0` is constant? If compiler know something is constant, it is likely to generate more efficient code

   - `x*x*x` : Just generates assembly for float value multiplication twice
   - `pow` : This must have considered all the exponent values so probably it has general code(less efficient, may include loops)

Comment: The compiler can inline or optimize `pow` because the C standard specifies how it behaves, and the external identifier `pow` is reserved for that purpose, so the compiler knows what it is required to do. Further, compilers and libraries may be bundled as part of one C implementation, so the implementation would have complete control over both the code generated by the compiler and the implementation of `pow`.

Comment: Well, I was answering to the question "why there is 5x difference?". And with `-O3` (without `-ffast-math`) it really calls `pow` function and it is slow. https://godbolt.org/z/Kx71W7 Let me know if i missed something.

Comment: If a particular compiler does not inline `pow` in a particular circumstance, then the reason is not that it cannot be inlined because `pow` is in a shared library; the reason is that the compiler’s design does not inline pow. This can be complicated by other considerations, but it is not a requirement of the C standard.

Comment: I get your point, and I'm not saying what I said is part of the standard. Just wanted to analyze the significant performance difference the OP asked.

Comment: The point is the statement is “`pow` can’t be as it is in a shared library” is false. Regardless of what you intended to analyze or convey, this answer presents false information and is therefore detrimental. In fact, [GCC and Clang do replace some calls to `pow` with inline code](https://godbolt.org/z/7PMEsq), including `pow(x, 3)` if `-ffast-math` is enabled. The second item, about constants, also misstates the situation; the code in the question has a hardcoded `3.0f`, so it is a constant; the text in this answer about having “general code” or consider all exponent values is inapplicable.

Comment: Oh I get that and updated the answer. Thanks.