# Why does hardcoded variable (2^62 + 1) subtracted by pow(2, 62) evaluate to 0 instead of 1?

Tags: c++

Why does this statement:

```
std::cout << 4611686018427387905 - pow(2.0, 62) << std::endl;
```

or:

```
unsigned long long int value = 4611686018427387905; //2^62 + 1
unsigned long long int result = value - pow(2.0, 62);
```

evaluate to 0 instead of 1? An unsigned long long int can hold up to 2^64 values so I don't think that is the issue. This also happens with other values that are very large.

Comment: Don't use `pow` for integer power operations. especially not if's 2 to the power of something. Try `unsigned long long int result = value - (1ULL << 62);`

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/11082165) and [Why isn't `int pow(int base, int exponent)` in the standard C++ libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2398442/11082165)

Comment: The `pow()` function returns a `double`, so your subtractions are done between 2 `double` operands ... and they have a precision of ~17 decimal digits. But your `unsigned long long` has 19 digits.

Comment: A `double` very typically has **52 bits** of unsigned precision.  That's why your `2^62 + 1` isn't looking so precise.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yeah, that looks like a correct duplicate to me.

Comment: Figured it out, thank you all!